# Automate daily collection of weather station data from NCDc

Tags: database, automation

[Here](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/climate/climatedata.html) is the link to where the data can be found. Scrolling down to Surface Data : Daily and selecting the Global and U. S. Web Page Icon. On the next page, Select the radio button Country and press continue. From the next page's drop down menu, select any state and then press the radio button for entire state (I need more than 100 stations per day).
The next page allows you to select the date range.
I am dumping these data files into excel and sorting (which is a pain, since it could obviously be

automated).
Is there a way I can access the most current data via a script (VBA or otherwise)? 
My main problem is that I can't send the server a simple request to obtain the data. Also, there is an FTP site but only allows .gz files to be downloaded, each over a gig, so its not reasonable for my situation.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There [National Climatic Data Center](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/ncdcwebservices) has several data APIs available for this.